# Bash file descriptor leak

Tags: bash

I get a file descriptor leak when running the following code:

```
function get_fd_count() {
        local fds
        cd /proc/$$/fd; fds=( * ) # avoid a StackOverflow source colorizer bug
        echo "${#fds[@]}"
}

function fd_leak_func() {
        while : ; do
                echo ">> Current FDs: $(get_fd_count)"
                read retval new_state < <(set +e; new_state=$(echo foo); retval=$?; printf "%d %s\n" $retval $new_state)
        done
}

fd_leak_func
```

Tested on both 3.2.25 and 4.0.28.

This only happens when the loop is happening within a function; every time we return to top-level context, the extra file descriptors are closed.

Is this intended behavior? More to the point, are workarounds available?

---

Followup: After reporting to the bash-bug mailing list, this was confirmed as a bug. Chet indicated that a fix will be included in the next release (as of 4/17/2010).

Comment: Even weirder, if I put a `true` at the end of the loop it keeps going up, but putting a `/bin/true` keeps it level at 5.

Comment: Report it to the newsgroup using the `bashbug` program and see what the maintainer, Chet Ramey, says about it.

Comment: Still leaks in CentOS 6 bash 4.1.2(1)-release.

Comment: Adding `/bin/true` does not help in my bash (version noted above), but adding (exit 0) does. My wild guess is that creating a subshell triggers some cleanup routine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simplified example:

```
$ fd_leaker() { while :; do read a < <(pwd); c=(/proc/$$/fd/*); c=${#c[@]}; echo $c; done; } 
$ fd_leaker
```

This one is not fixed by using `/bin/true` but it's mostly fixed by using `(exit 0)` But I get "bash: echo: write error: Interrupted system call" errors using that "fix" or if I use `/bin/pwd` instead of the builtin `pwd`.

It also seems to be specific to `read`. I tried `grep . < <(pwd) > /dev/null` and it worked properly. When I tried `while read a; do :; done < <( pwd)`

The extra file descriptors in the form of:

```
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 2010-04-15 19:26 39 -> pipe:[8357879]
```

I really don't think the runaway creation of them is intended, after all there's nothing recursive going on. I really don't see how adding something in the loop should fix things.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a `/bin/true` at the end of the loop fixes it, but I don't know why or how, or why it happens in the first place.

Comment: I see it in versions 4.0.33(1)-release, 4.1.0(1)-release and 3.2.49(23)-release. It also seems to fix it if I put an `(exit 0)` "no-op" subshell at the end of the loop instead of `/bin/true` (which works for me as well).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be fixed in bash-4.2. I tested with bash-4.2.28 particularly